# Will Paypal send recurring payment IPN notification every month

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am setting up a subscription system in my website. It is monthly subscription system and I am using Paypal Express checkout for it.

My question is **will Paypal send IPN notification to the notify_url every month when the user's account is charged, or only when the first payment is made** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal will send notifications every month to your IPN Listener that should be specified and enabled in `Profile > My Selling Tools > Instant payment notifications`

Every recurring payment notification will contain `txn_type=subscr_payment`

Comment: Will the `txn_id` be unique per notification sent ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get IPN's for future transactions on recurring payments profile you'll need to make sure you have IPN configured in the PayPal account profile.  It will **not** continually use the original NotifyURL value.

Answer (score 1):

In my current testing with PayPal I see the following txn_types;

txn_type => recurring_payment_profile_created

For the first time ONLY its created plus and then each recurring time, this notification for each payment cycle;

txn_type => recurring_payment

Plus as others have stated it will use the IPN URL specified in the PayPal profile.

When you first create the payment profile you will receive back a tracking code Profile ID and this is also sent at each notification.  Look for [recurring_payment_id] and match against this in your database to keep track of what is happening to the subscription (changes/user cancellations etc).